# SelectMany taking a huge amount of memory using ReactiveExtensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I want to create a pipeline that takes images and returns some derived objects.

I'm using a sequence of bitmaps and for each of them I perform the task (that is asynchronous). So it's as simple as it seems. However, I found out that the memory consumption is REALLY HIGH. To illustrate the problem I've created this test that you can run.

Please, take a look at the memory because it will take up to 400 MB of RAM.

What can I do to avoid taking so much memory? What's happening here?

```
[Fact]
public async Task BitmapPipelineTest()
{
    var bitmaps = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => new WriteableBitmap(800, 600, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, new BitmapPalette(new List<Color>() { new Color() })));
    var bitmapsObs = bitmaps.ToObservable();

    var processed = bitmapsObs.SelectMany(bitmap => DoSomethingAsync(bitmap));
    processed.Subscribe();

    await Task.Delay(20000);
}

private async Task<object> DoSomethingAsync(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return new object();
}
```

Comment: If you search around for 'WriteableBitmap' and 'Memory leak', there are a lot of posters experiencing the same problem, and a lack of good solutions.  If you don't need to use the WriteableBitmap (ie, if you're not doing UI work), then I would use the Bitmap class, and modify your code to create/dispose the Bitmap with a using statement inside the SelectMany

Comment: @Andrew - It could be related to the issue you describe.  I think it depends on the version of .NET the OP is using.  It looks like the memory issue was addressed in 4.0.  In my tests using .NET 4.5 the memory does grow out of control quickly but it does eventually get garbage collected so I don't think there is a memory leak.

Comment: @JasonBoyd - Interesting, using 4.5, I was able to blow the max memory allocation (2Gb) and crash the process.  Putting a call to GC.Collect() after the bitmap was out of scope in my modified code didn't prevent it either (though I would never consider putting a GC call like that into production anyway)

Comment: @Andrew - Yeah, I glossed over a lot when I said 'it does eventually get garbage collected' due to the limited space in comments.  In fact, if I let it run unchecked my application would crash as well.  However, I was able to free memory by directly calling `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` which suggested to me that it was not a memory leak but, rather, an issue with the GC schedule (which is what I address in my answer).  I was also able to get the GC to fire by running them in batches of two hundred behind a button click event handler.

Answer (score 2):

So I don't think the issue is necessarily due to `SelectMany` or even reactive extensions.  It looks like the `WriteableBitmap` uses unmanaged memory: [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/WriteableBitmap.cs).  I believe the issue is that you are, in very rapid succession, creating a bunch of relatively small managed objects that take up a much larger amount of unmanaged memory.  From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If a small managed object allocates a large amount of unmanaged memory, the runtime takes into account only the managed memory, and thus underestimates the urgency of scheduling garbage collection.

But we can give the garbage collector hints by using the `GC.AddMemoryPressure` and `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure` functions.  This will help the GC improve its scheduling.  Before we can do that we need to have some idea of the amount of unmanaged memory being allocated.  I believe the unmanaged memory is used to store the pixel array so I think a good estimate is the pixel width times the pixel height times the number of bits in each channel times the number of channels.  From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx) it looks like there are 32 bits (4 bytes) per channel and 4 channels.

I ran some tests using code similar to the following and got really good results:

```
var processed = 
    Enumerable
    .Range(0, 100)
    .Select(_ => new WriteableBitmap(
        800, 
        600, 
        96, 
        96, 
        PixelFormats.Bgr24, 
        new BitmapPalette(new List<Color>() { new Color() })))
    .Select(x => new { Bitmap = x, ByteSize = x.PixelWidth * x.PixelHeight * 4 * 4)
    .ToObservable()
    .Do(x => GC.AddMemoryPressure(x.ByteSize))
    .SelectMany(x => DoSomethingAsync(x.Bitmap));

processed
.Subscribe(x => GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(x.ByteSize));
```

However, if your source is publishing bitmaps faster than you can handle them then you are still going to have issues.  The back pressure will cause memory to be allocated faster than it can be deallocated.

Honestly though, are you really having bitmaps pushed to you?  I have no idea what your actual program looks like but in your example code that is clearly a pull based system.  If it is a pull based system have you considered [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx)?  PLINQ is great for this type of thing; it gives you really good control over concurrency and you will not have to worry about back pressure.

Comment: Great (and correct) usage of a `Do` statement. Good to see an example that isn't just logging.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - Props from the man that wrote the book.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like to me that you're running into a simple memory usage issue.

If there are 4 bytes per channel and 4 channels per pixel then your 1000 images at 800 x 600 each are 1000 x 800 x 600 x 4 x 4 = 733MB (approx.).

What strikes me, though, in your code that could be giving you grief is that you're starting with a enumerable, then turning it into an observable, which is built using tasks, which, in the end, you run asynchronously with a fire and forget `.Subscribe()` and you fudge the return with an `await Task.Delay(20000);`. It's all prone to errors. You should avoid mixing your "monads".

Here's how I would write it:

```
public async Task BitmapPipelineTest()
{
    await
        Observable
            .Range(0, 100)
            .Select(_ => new WriteableBitmap(
                800, 600, 96, 96,
                PixelFormats.Bgr24,
                new BitmapPalette(new List<Color>() { new Color() })))
            .SelectMany(x =>
                Observable
                    .Start(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                        return new object();
                    }));
}
```